# ACRA Application Crash Library Does not Catch Device Exception

Tags: android, debugging, logcat, error-log, acra

I am using the latest ACRA library to get crash report from a real Android device. However, when app crashes ACRA Toast does show and I cannot get crash report.

Here is my MainApplication.java:

```
package com.mydomain.myapp;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

import org.acra.ACRA;
import org.acra.ReportField;
import org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode;
import org.acra.annotation.ReportsCrashes;

@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "http://example.com/debug.php", mailTo = "myname@mydomain.com", //formUri ="http://yourserver.com/yourscript",
  customReportContent = { ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,    ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT },
  mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
  //mode = ReportingInteractionMode.SILENT //,
resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text) //, logcatArguments = { "-t", "100", "-v", "long", "ActivityManager:I", "MyApp:D", "*:S" }
public class MyMapApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
  ACRA.init(this); //switching this did not work with super.onCreate()
  super.onCreate();

  // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA



}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
  super.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onTerminate() {
  super.onTerminate();
}


}
```

AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<application
android:name=".MyMapApp"

...

<service
android:name="org.acra.sender.SenderService"
android:exported="false"
android:process=":acra" />
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.2'
}
```

I already setup email account on the device.  How come this does not catch up application crash?

Comment: As pointed out on Github you are not using the latest version of ACRA (which is currently 4.8.2) and you are using config from ACRA-4.8.2 that is not relavent to ACRA-4.6.2 (eg SenderService). You also specify both formUri and MailTo.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the core libraries where crashing the program.  ACRA only catches crashes in Java Virtual machine.  I had to first root the device. The using adb get into /data/towbstone/ and file the dump files there.  This told me what exact libraries where crashing the app.